A bar plot using PSTricks
I found the code below in a PDF; see p. 76 of
https://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-plot/doc/pst-plot-doc.pdf
In the PDF, I couldn't find the data (that is, \bardata), but just for a test, how I can draw a bar plot like the one in the top of page 76? Any help/hint is very welcome.
\psset{xunit=.44cm,yunit=.3cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-3)(29,13)
\psaxes[axesstyle=axes,Ox=1466,Oy=0,Dx=4,Dy=2,ticksize=-4pt 0,
ylabelFactor={\,\%}]{-}(29,12)
\listplot[linecolor=blue,plotstyle=bar,barwidth=0.3cm,
fillcolor=red,fillstyle=vlines]{\barData}
\listplot[showpoints=true]{\barData}
\rput{90}(-3,6.25){Amount}
\end{pspicture}


(personally, I would use pgfplots if you want to do plots in latex)

Can you provide an example using pgfplots? With thanks.

There are plenty of examples in the manual and at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgfplots

can be found in the source of the documentation!
\def\barData{
    0 0.03
    1 0.11
    2 0.28
    3 0.84
    4 6.70
    5 8.55
    6 8.77
    7 11.09
    8 7.18
    9 6.20
    10 5.78
    11 4.19
    12 2.37
    13 2.26
    14 1.68
    15 1.03
    16 1.37
    17 1.34
    18 0.92
    19 0.67
    20 0.87
    21 1.20
    22 1.98
    23 3.99
    24 5.08
    25 5.17
    26 5.78
    27 4.44
    28 0.11
}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-plot}
\begin{document}

\psset{xunit=.44cm,yunit=.3cm}
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-3)(29,13)
    \psaxes[axesstyle=axes,Ox=1466,Oy=0,Dx=4,Dy=2,ticksize=-4pt 0,
    ylabelFactor={\,\%}]{-}(29,12)
    \listplot[linecolor=blue,plotstyle=bar,barwidth=0.3cm,
    fillcolor=red,fillstyle=vlines]{\barData}
    \listplot[showpoints=true]{\barData}
    \rput{90}(-3,6.25){Amount}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}



Thank you very much.
